# Django request.GET[] string comparison failing

Tags: python, django

Here is my code snippet from a view function in django-

```
    dir = ''
    if (''+request.GET['dir']) == 'U':
      dir = 'U'
      elif (''+request.GET['dir']) == 'D':
      dir = 'D'
```

But when I check to see if dir == 'D' or dir == 'U', the comparison fails. For eg. following code fails (same for comparing with 'U')

```
    if dir == 'D':
      user_voted.vote = 'D'
      obj.score -= 2
      user_voted.save()
      obj.save()
```

I feel the dir is not setting to 'U' or 'D'. I even tried setting dir = request.GET['dir'] which should set it to 'U' or 'D' but the comparisons still fail. Can anyone tell me if request.GET is returning non-string or string to char comparison is causing this or I'm setting it incorrectly or what.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Can you print out what the values are? There's not enough information here.

Comment: What is the point of this `''+request.GET['dir']` pattern?

Comment: Daniel, I was trying that to cast dir to string explicitly since the comparisons were not working if I assigned dir = request.GET['dir']

Comment: @jterrace request URL is GET /vote/?id=1&type=link&dir=D' HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are concatenating strings and reassigning variables. Try simplify it:

```
dir = request.GET.get('dir', None)
if dir == "U":
    ...
elif dir =="D":
    ...
```

If that's still not working, try to print the `request.GET` dictionary to see if there actually is a `dir` parameter being passed (there should be)

Comment: Pastylegs, I tried that too but it still doesn't work and my request URL is "GET /vote/?id=1&type=link&dir=D' HTTP/1.1", so I do believe that the dir is set correctly in the get request. The code within 'if dir == 'U' or dir == 'D' never gets executed.